# Ubuntu virtual box machine is deleted automatically

Tags: dual-boot, server, 20.04, virtualbox, oracle

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in virtual box, and it was running fine for 2-3 days.

After when I started or powered-on the machine, the boot process showed "checking disks ..." and offers to install Ubuntu again.

The virtual machine worked fine after installing the OS, but now when I boot it, it keeps prompting the installer and not the OS installed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your installation media (virtual CD drive holding the ISO file) is still attached, causing your virtual BIOS to boot into the installation file again and again.

Notice this icon at your connected hardware panel.

[image]

The solution would be to disable this device (or remove the iso file from it) from your VirtualBox virtual machine settings, resulting the virtual BIOS to boot directly to the OS (which is the next boot order option).